# getUid() gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

My app crashes because of getUid() null pointer exception.

This is MainActivity.If there is no user in the database,then the user is directed to login page.If the user tries to Log in and he/she has not signd up before(doesn't exist),then he/she is directed to the setup Intent.As far as I know,the user once logged in does not remain logged in forever.Is it the reason for getUid returning null?How to solve it?
following is the code:

```
package com.awani.pocketblog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Set;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mBlogList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
private boolean mProcessLike = false;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseCurrentUser;//to retrieve data from the current user.
private Query mQueryCurrentUser;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

    //if there is no user signed in,go to loginIntent    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()==null)
            {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }

        }
    };

    mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

    //problem is with the following statement:
    String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabaseCurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

    mQueryCurrentUser = mDatabaseCurrentUser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserID);

    mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);

//check if the user trying to login exists or not
    checkUserExist();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
//set adpter for recyclerview
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.blog_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mQueryCurrentUser

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

           final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());//model means Blog class over here
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());

            viewHolder.setLikeButton(post_key);
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            //mView is reference for the whole view
            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent singleBlogIntent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,BlogSingleActivity.class);
                    singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id",post_key);
                   // singleBlogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(singleBlogIntent);


                }
            });


            viewHolder.mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mProcessLike = true;

                        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (mProcessLike) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();

                                        mProcessLike = false;


                                    } else {
                                        mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Random value");
                                       mProcessLike = false;
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }


            });

        }

    };


    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

private void checkUserExist() {

    //retrieving UID

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) {
        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        //check if the user with this UID already  exists
        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {

                    Intent setUpIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetUpActivity.class);
                    setUpIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(setUpIntent);

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}

//holder for the recyclerView
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    View mView;
    ImageButton mLikeButton;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        mLikeButton = (ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);

        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);


    }

    public void setLikeButton(final String post_key){


        mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                    mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red_400_24dp);

                }else{
                    mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void setTitle(String title){

      TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_title.setText(title);

    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){

        TextView post_description = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        post_description.setText(desc);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        TextView post_username = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
        post_username.setText(username);

    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx,String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_add){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class));
    }

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_logout){
        logout();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void logout() {

    mAuth.signOut();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The wrong line is :

```
String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You need to test if the current user exist first :

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    String currentUserID = user.getUid();

    // Use currentUserID 
}
```

[Firebase User documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)